# Zoom, pan image and perform gestures on ios swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm a newbie to swift development and I was looking for help for this use case of panning, zooming image and gestures.
On android this library provides all the functionalities
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Any help from people who have solved this on the iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed/able to use UIKit, this works very well for me:

```
import UIKit

class PanZoomImageViewController : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: image?.size.width ?? 0, height: image?.size.height ?? 0)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0

        imageView.image = image
    }

    @IBAction private func dismiss()
    {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
    {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works for zooming and panning, how to apply gestures and observe for taps specific to the image bounds ? any idea ?

Comment: @Fareedkhan  What gestures?  What do you mean with "taps specific to image bounds"?

Comment: when I pan the image in the scroll view, and single/double tap, I want to get the coordinates of the image at the tapped place instead of the screen coordinates.

Comment: @Fareedkhan you should be able to get that using `UIScrollView`'s `content[Size|Offset|...]` properties and the size of the image.  Give it a try.

Comment: I tried using the offset to determine the shift of the origin  from (0,0) but then when I pan after zooming in, the offset remains constant. How to calculate coordinates during the pan ?